# Python Selenium Firefox on Ubuntu: New Tabs Not Working

Tags: python, firefox, ubuntu, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm doing remote web crawling and scraping, and hoping not to reload a new browser window for every link on one page.

The problem is that new tabs are not opening up with my Firefox web driver.

Here's what I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

# launch our headless display 
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# launch our web driver and get a page
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com/")

# try to open a new tab
ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

# this should print 2, but it prints 1, because new tab not opened
print len(browser.window_handles)

# clean up everything
browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Specifications:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2
- Python 2.7.6
- Selenium 2.47.1
- PyVirtualDisplay 0.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this response from a Selenium developer](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/935), new tabs in Firefox are not supported as of August 2015.  He suggested exploring [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) but currently its dependencies cause more trouble than it's worth, at least for my use case.  His solution is to just use new windows (`driver.execute_script("window.open()")`), instead of new tabs.